# Algorithm design to partition a set of students into groups

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, dynamic-programming, computer-science

I'm learning algorithm design and I saw this problem: Problem: We have n students in (numbered from 1 to n). Students need to be divided into group for in-class activities. Each student has a preference in terms of how many students are present in their group. Specifically, student i wishes that the number of students in their group is between x[i] and y[i] (inclusive). In other words, if the group (that student i is assigned to) has G people, then x[i] ≤ G ≤ y[i] must hold. Every student must be assigned to a group (even if the group consists only of 1 student).
Given n and x[], y[]'s, algorithm should determine whether this is possible or not.

Below are some examples:

Example 1: n = 5, (x[], y[]) = { (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 3)}.

We can assign student 1 and student 4 to one group (this group's size is 2) and the other three students to another group. This would satisfy everyone's constraint.

Example 2: n = 5, (x[], y[]) = { (1, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 3)}.

It is impossible to satisfy student 5's constraint because there are only two students who are "OK" with a group of size 3 (yet student 5 only wants to have exactly 3 students in the group).

Example 3: n = 5, (x[], y[]) = { (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 5), (2, 4)}.

Student 1 can be assigned to a solo-group. Students 2-5 can be arbitrarily assigned to two groups of size two (as everyone is OK with 2 students in their group). Hence, many solutions exist.

My first idea is to sort the array by y[i] and then starting from the first element, put people in groups depends on the value of y[i]. But what will happen in case of example 2?

My second idea is to sort the array by x[i]+y[i], since y[i] is greater than x[i], we can start from the first element and put people in group ( but i think first idea is better)

Overall, I think these 2 algorithms are not sufficient, I'm looking for something more sufficient (If there is)

Comment: Interesting problem, may I ask where did u find this problem?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64830299/1, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/132225/755. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @SerialLazer, [apparently](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/132225/algorithm-design-to-partition-a-set-of-students?noredirect=1#comment278368_132225) it was from HackerRank, but my request to provide a direct link never got a response.  Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 0):

I think your first solution is brilliant, and there isn't any problem with Example 2.

1. Of course you sort the array by y[i] first. Then you start from the **biggest** to the smallest.
2. If a group can't be created in this size- you make sure it's fine to move to a smaller size (e.g. there isn't a group with a "strict" condition of this only one possible size). In case 2, for instance- it would be impossible as student 5 doesn't have this option, so the algorithm would immediately return False.

Answer (score 0):

I found a polynomial solution to this, primarily based on sorting on the condition of how restrictive the preferences are.

#### Notice a couple of things:

1. If someone has a preference like `[x, x]` => this is the most restrictive since we ought to find him a group of exactly size `x`
2. On the flip side, a loose-preference-size `for ex. [1, 1000]` => its the least restrictive and **doesnt have to be taken into account until more restrictive preferences are considered**
3. While forming groups, once the max-size is reached => **assume that the group is formed** ; for example `[1,1]` => `group of size 1 is ready`

#### Code-Preparation :: class=Group

While implementing, I figured its going to be much easier if I create a `Group class` to maintain:

1. all the members of the group (members as in their preferences)
2. consolidated min-size of the group
3. consolidated max-size of the group
4. validity-checker-method to figure out if the group is eventually valid. For example `[(3, 3), (2, 3)]` **is not a valid-group**

#### How to start with the initial Preference-list

As discussed above, we need to sort the preference-list based on most-restristive to least-restrictive preferences i.e. `y[i]-x[i]`

#### Time-complexity: O(N^2)

#### Here is the working-code in Python:

```
from typing import List

class Group:
    def __init__(self, s: int, e: int):
        self.members = [(s, e)]
        self.min, self.max = s, e

    def add_member(self, s: int, e: int):
        self.members.append((s, e))
        self.min, self.max = max(self.min, s), min(self.max, e)

    def can_fit(self, s: int, e: int) -> bool:
        return not (self.reached_maxsize() or (e < self.min or s > self.max))

    def reached_maxsize(self) -> bool:
        return len(self.members) == self.max

    def check_group_validity(self) -> bool:
        num_members = len(self.members)
        return self.min <= num_members <= self.max


def create_groups(preference_list):
    groups: List[Group] = []
    preference_list = sorted(preference_list, key=lambda x: (x[1] - x[0], x[0], x[1]))

    for pref in preference_list:
        found_group = False
        for grp in groups:
            if grp.can_fit(pref[0], pref[1]):
                grp.add_member(pref[0], pref[1])
                found_group = True
                break
        if not found_group:
            groups.append(Group(pref[0], pref[1]))

    # check groups-validity
    if all(group.check_group_validity() for group in groups):
        return groups

    print("No grouping is possible")
    return []


res = create_groups([(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 3)])
print([x.members for x in res])

res = create_groups([(1, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 3)])
print([x.members for x in res])

res = create_groups([(1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 5), (2, 4)])
print([x.members for x in res])
```

#### Test-output:

```
[[(2, 2), (1, 2)], [(3, 3), (2, 3), (1, 3)]]

No grouping is possible
[]

[[(1, 1)], [(2, 2), (2, 2)], [(2, 4), (2, 5)]]
```